# How do you indicate errors in handling messages in window procedures?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm currently authoring a library to handle information from the Raw Input API and I'm handling everything with *cascading functions*. This has resulted in several, very small, very readable, and very focused functions.

But, it has just hit me that I don't understand how to **properly** indicate failure to Windows. I have the function:

```
/* OnInput: Handle data received from Windows via a `WM_INPUT` message. */
static LRESULT CALLBACK OnInput(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL DispatchRawInput(CONST PRAWINPUT);

    assert(msg == WM_INPUT);

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And it returns zero [as the documentation states it should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx); but this assumes success.

The actual text states:

> "If an application processes this message, it should return zero."

But what do I do if I *can't* handle it? I originally assumed you'd just call `DefWindowProc` and leave it at that but that doesn't signal to Windows that anything happened.

The message `WM_CREATE` seems to be the only instance I can find that returns something other than zero:

> "If an application processes this message, it should return zero to continue creation of the window. If the application returns –1, the window is destroyed and the CreateWindowEx or CreateWindow function returns a NULL handle."

Is error handling really just up to the programmer/team and not a necessity to inform the operating system? What about events like `WM_CREATE` that fail and need to prevent the creation of a window?

Comment: How exactly should Windows respond if you have an error? Answer: it doesn't really care. It provided the message, it's *your* responsibility to do the right thing with it. With the occasional exception as you noted with `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: You are reading something into the documentation that's not really there. You equate "message was handled" with "success". With that you conclude that Windows must have something in stock to deal with failure. It doesn't, as Mark pointed out above. `WM_CREATE` is different from other messages in that it's technically a callback from `CreateWindow` that lets you abort window creation if you decide to. Again, this is not an error handling facility.

Comment: Ah, I must have got caught up in the the return value _always_ needing to have some sort of meaning. Got the wrong end of the stick completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate errors according to the documentation for each message. If the message doesn't say anything about errors, then you can safely assume that the message has no error indicator. That's common for notification messages, where the OS is simply telling you that something has happened. It doesn't need a response from you.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer just because the statement "the OS is simply telling you that something has happened." seems for inline with my new understanding.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a fatal error, then you should handle it the same as an other fatal error: inform the user of the error somehow (`MessageBox`, `stderr`, etc.) and `exit()` or `abort()`.

If it's a non-fatal error, then you need to communicate that back to your application, which can be done in a number of ways: set a flag, call a function, post a `WM_APP` message, etc., and your application should handle it.  All in all, Windows doesn't really care, and it's your responsibility to handle the error in a reasonable fashion.

If you're writing a library intended to be used by others, then make sure your application has a clearly defined and documented error procedure.  If an internal error happens within your library, then allow the application to specify an error callback, and then call that callback and let the application handle it.

Comment: `WM_USER` messages are private to control implementations. Don't confuse them with application private messages, `WM_APP + x`, which you should use in the scenario you describe.

Comment: @IInspectable: `WM_USER` messages are private to the window class, while `WM_APP` messages are private to the window instance.  So if it's an application-created window, it's likely to also be an application-created window class, in which case either `WM_USER` or `WM_APP` could be used.  But you're right that in the general case, `WM_APP` would be more appropriate for this.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/02/55914.aspx