# what to return or to do in a winapi window procedure in order to intercept an error and produce an error log entry

Tags: c, winapi

We have a c program.
One policy in the development of this program is:

> "Every function/method that can fail should have a return value and should
>   return the appropriate value in case of an error. No exception like
>   behaviour."

So, in the case of an error, our program produces a cascading error report, because every function returns an error flag.

My problem is with the Window Procedure.

In c WinAPI I process a button click event `(WM_COMMAND signal)` in a separate function. If there is an error, I make an error log entry and return 0.

In the window procedure, where I called the function, if the function returns 0, I produce an error log entry and, what now, what value should I return to the window procedure in order to achieve it, that this chain of error logs and error return values does not break?

I understand from the stackoverflow post: [How do you indicate errors in handling messages in window procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18497551/4228131)

that windows does not care about my error.

I also know that the `WM_CREATE` signal is other than the rest.

But I just want to send an appropriate return value. Is this 0?

MSDN does not help me:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx

> "The return value is the result of the message processing and depends on the message sent."

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Note that MSDN *will* somewhat help you, e.g. the docs for [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) says you should return 0 if you process the message(even if whatever you're doing in response to that message fails) , while e.g. for [WM_MENUDRAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647606(v=vs.85).aspx) the return value has another meaning. But the return value of the WindowProc isn't to be used to cascade errors of your own , using values that the windows API doesn't expect.

Comment: There is actually a way to "return" a failure code from a windows procedure, PostQuitMessage, but I doubt that's what you want since it ends the thread's message loop (and normally ends your program if it's the main or only thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only apply your policy to functions whose prototypes are in your control. A window procedure is out of your control. The meaning of the return value is not determined by you. The Windows API determines that, and does so in a way that is not compatible with your policy.

You simply have to accept that your policy cannot be applied here. In the case of a `WM_COMMAND` window procedure you cannot cascade an error because the caller, the Win32 framework, doesn't follow your policy. The best you can do is log the error and then return from the window procedure a value as stipulated by the documentation. In this case it is zero since you handled the message.

Comment: Thank you. So, in your opinion, what is the best way in c winapi?

Comment: Well, it depends on the particular API. If you are calling an API function then detect error on its return value and then cascade on. But for WM_COMMAND you have a callback. That cannot return an error. You cannot cascade on because Windows isn't going to play along. So log the error and then return from the window proc as the docs instruct.

Answer (score -1):

The return value of the window proc only has a meaning for the window manager. So, you should always return 0 if you have processed the message. Otherwise, you should call DefWindowProc and return its value.

However, this is the exact opposite for dialog boxes that are created through functions such as CreateDialog or DialogBox: in this case, you should return TRUE if you have processed the message, and FALSE otherwise, without calling DefWindowProc.

Comment: If you want to delete your answer you should delete it, not vandalise it.

Comment: And I suspect the reason your answer got voted down is because it is inaccurate. The value you should return varies for each message - saying you should "always return 0" is incorrect.

Comment: I said "should", not "must". And I answer a question, therefore I was obviously speaking of the same message than the author.
Anyway, even for WM_COMMAND, it's a mistake to return 0 in some cases. And I "vandalise" nothing: unlike you, I edit only my own message.

Comment: Semantics, "should always" means effectively the same thing as "must", and if you want to add a qualification you should be clear about it and not assume people will know what you mean. You'll need to develop a thicker skin if you want to hang around on SO - a single downvote on an answer is seriously not that big a deal.

Comment: I get downvotes all the time on Stack Overflow, and I hate it. I really do. But in this case I understand why this answer got down voted. I however don't understand why he is acting like this. Did he have prior bad experience? He use the key word 'the' message, so probably in his mind he assumed he specified the specific message. But he started off by stating a 'window procedure is out of your control'. Which signifies the window procedure in general. I actually read his answer and got the impression that you always return 0 from the window procedure. But I know this is not the case.

Comment: @user13947194: This is what you get when you share your experience: just hate and incomprehension. But even after all these years, I still think my answer is perfectly valid. The bad point of this website is that your words do no longer belong to you once posted.

Comment: For example, `WM_MOVING` must return TRUE if processed.